# How to get the stdout from a Test::Script run?

Tags: perl, testing

I want to test of Perl script, say testme.pl, with the [Test::Script](http://search.cpan.org/~plicease/Test-Script-1.14/lib/Test/Script.pm) module and get the stdout of the executed script. I get an `undef` so far.

Here is what I tried (test file `test.t`):

```
use Test::More tests => 2;
use Test::Script;       
use Data::Dumper;
script_compiles('testme.pl');
my $out;
script_runs(['testme.pl'], {"stdout"=>$out}, 'run_script');
print "Out is " . Dumper($out);
```

And the script to be tested (`testme.pl`)

```
print "catchme if you can\n";

boris@midkemia artif_get_file $ perl perl_test.pl 
1..2
ok 1 - Script testme.pl compiles
ok 2 - run_script
Out is $VAR1 = undef;
```

I also tried using an array ref \@out instead of $out, still no luck. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: `{ stdout => \$out }` ?

Comment: @toolic Nope, I want to perform more advanced testing/matching on the output and I feel more comfortable with the full stdout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've almost got it. You need to [give the `stdout` option a reference](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Script#script_runs). Otherwise you're just passing in `undef` and it will ignore the option.

```
script_runs(['testme.pl'], {"stdout"=>\$out}, 'run_script');
```

Comment: Ouahou. It works perfectly.. I have to admit I don't use scalar refs very often. Thank you @schwern!